# Big Recursive SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have the following relation in my database;

```
  Column  |         Type         | Modifiers 
----------+----------------------+-----------
 country1 | character varying(4) | not null
 country2 | character varying(4) | not null
 length   | numeric              |
```

with example data

```
 country1 | country2 | length 
----------+----------+--------
 AL       | GR       |    282
 AL       | MK       |    151
 AL       | MNE      |    172
 AL       | KOS      |    112
```

and I would like to write a recursive query where I find all the countries that can be reached overland from France. How would I go about doing this?

I have come up with this so far:

```
WITH Recursive frborders(country) AS
(
SELECT country1 FROM borders WHERE country2 = 'FR'
)

SELECT name FROM frborders;
```

But I'm not getting the desired result, how would I go about doing this? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: You should probably specify what database you're using.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL but don't want to use syntax limited to it.

Comment: FYI, if you're using PostgreSQL, then you can only use syntax that is valid in PostgreSQL.

Comment: pure sql only allows for queries giving you the result for a maximum number of atomic segments which needs to be known in advance (afaik hierarchical queries have not yet been adopted by the standards though  most rdbms have syntax to support them).

Comment: What I meant was that I don't want to use syntax that is SPECIFIC to PostgreSQL. Anyhow, any ideas how to solve this? :)

Comment: Why is it that people never want to exploit the tools they have? Do you code your web application such that it is independent of the Web framework you use? Do you code your application such that it is independent of the programming language you use?

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this (at least in the direction you are going) will be different in different on different platforms. On PostgreSQL you need to actually call your statement recursively, thus:

```
WITH RECURSIVE frborders (country1, path) AS (
   SELECT country1, ARRAY['FR']::varchar[] AS "array"
    FROM borders
    WHERE country2 = 'FR'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT borders.country1, borders.country2||path
    FROM frborders, borders
    WHERE borders.country2 = frborders.country1
)
select * from frborders;
```

does something like what I imagine you want. I added a path to make this clearer to me.

The syntax on SQL Server is similar but different and no arrays so the path won't work (but you didn't want that anyway). On MySQL you can do this using temporary tables and stored procedures but it looks nothing like this. There is a platform independent way to do this but it requires a very different table structure. Also, you need at least one border entry for 'FR'.

Comment: Recursive common table expressions *are* the platform independent way to do this. Although the syntax varies slightly this *is* supported by all modern DBMS (except MySQL - which is hardly "modern" anyway)